# getting String out of bounds exception

Tags: java

the code compiles and also works for any string that is passed but it doesn't work for checking the vowels. It throws a String out of bounds error and i have no idea why. the check for consonants is working.

Here is the code:

```
public String catchword(String word){
     int x = 0;
     for(x=0; x<word.length()+1; x++){  
         boolean v = Vowel(word.charAt(x));
         boolean c = Consonant(word.charAt(x));
         if (x<word.length()-1){
             v = Vowel(word.charAt(x+1));
         } else{
             v = true;
         }

         if (c == true && v == true){
             word = word.substring(0,x+1) + "op" + word.substring(x+1,word.length());
             x = x+3;
         } 
     }
     System.out.print(word);
     return word;
 }
```

Comment: `for(x=0; x<word.length()+1; x++)` <-- read that carefully. Then consider `word.charAt(x)` and `word.charAt(x+1)`.

Comment: ahh. i see the problem now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `for(x=0; x<word.length()+1; x++)`

```
x<word.length()+1
```

Should be

```
x<word.length()-1
```

The max index of `word` is `word.length()-1`

You will also have problem in `word.charAt(x+1)`. `word.length() - 1` is the max index, when `x` will be equal to it you will get again `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: thanks! it's working now